# TranslateColors() color range of RGB and CMYK

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am using the API TranslateColors() to convert RGB to CYMK. I could convert it.

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2007-10/msg00049.html

In the above sample RGB value is left shifted by 8 and passed to the above function. And the result, CYMK is right shifted by 8.

As I know CYMK values vary from 0 to 1. But the result are more than 1.

Can any one tell me how to get the CYMK values in 0-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGB values are between the range  `0-255`
to get this range between `0-1`
you will need to do:

```
ic[0].rgb.red = (255.0 / 255.0) << 8 ;
ic[0].rgb.green = (0 / 255.0);
ic[0].rgb.blue = (0 / 255.0);
```

basically

```
value = value / max_range_of_value;
```

make sure the variables used are `floats` or `decimals` (or anything that supports decimals).

Comment: click on the link in my question there is a sample

Comment: @UmeshaMS sorry about that, my code was extremely close to yours though, edited in answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: i want to know what is the max_range_of_value for CYMK. for RGB (253,253,253) i get CYMK(64630, 64630, 64630). what is the max_range_of_value for CMYK.

Comment: I do not understand your question, why arn't you using what I suggested and getting an `RGB` value of `RGB(0.99, 0.99, 0.99)`?
You stated in your question that: `CYMK values vary from 0 to 1` so the `max_range_of_value` for CMYK is 1.